# Отлавливание кодов ошибок в nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть сайт, фронтэнд и бекэнд, всё это работает через nginx. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отловить коды ошибок 404 и 50х.

```
location @front {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://front:3010;
}
location /back {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @back;
}
location @back {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://back:3000;
}
```

Comment: Ничего непонятно, но вангую, что вам нужен `proxy_intercept_errors`

Answer (score 1):

Например так передаём обработку ошибки в именованный location:

```
error_page 404 = @fallback;

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```